# $n\cdot \phi(n)=m\cdot \phi(m)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function

If I am not mistaken here in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C%202%2C%206%2C%208%2C%2020%2C%2012%2C%2042%2C%2032%2C%2054%2C%2040%2C%20110%2C%2048%2C%20156%2C%2084&sort=&language=english&go=Search) says that

$n\cdot \phi(n)=m\cdot \phi(m)$ is possible only if $n=m$.

$\phi(n)$  denotes Euler's totient function.

Is there a proof of this fact?

Comment: Yes, there is. The linked Luca & Munagi paper has it as part of Theorem 2  on page 3.

Comment: @Lisa I don't understand. The only related fact I can find in that paper is that $a(n,n) = n \phi(n)$. Is $a(n,n)$ easily shown to never take the same value twice?

Comment: $\phi(n)/n$ is injective as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose $n$ is the smallest number such that a number $m\ne n$ exists with

$$n\ \phi(n)=m\ \phi(m)$$

Let $p$ be the largest prime factor of $n$ and $q$ be the largest prime factor 
of $m$. Then, $p<q$ is impossible because $n\ \phi(n)$ would not be divisivle
by $q$. $p>q$ is impossible because $m\ \phi(m)$ would not be divisible by $p$.
So, we have $p=q$.

The valuation of $p$ in $n\ \phi(n)$ is uniquely determined
by the valuation of $p$ in $n$, so the valuations of $p$ in $n\ \phi(n)$ and
$m\ \phi(m)$ must coincide.

Therefore we have $\frac{n}{p}\phi(\frac{n}{p})=\frac{m}{p}\phi(\frac{m}{p})$

contradicting the assumption that $n$ is the smallest number, such that
an $m$ exists with $n\ \phi(n)=m\ \phi(m)$.

Hence $n=1$, but $1=m\ \phi(m)$ has the only solution $m=1$.

Comment: You might consider submitting this proof to the OEIS sequence mentioned in the question!

Comment: I feel very stupid, but if $p<q$, I see that $q$ cannot divide $n$.  But why can't it divide $\phi(n)$?

Comment: @JasonDeVito The prime factors of $\phi(n)$ cannot exceed the largest prime factor of $n$